# How STO works with the settings "Send at Einstein's optimal default time" in journeys if optimal time falls outside the STO configured window?

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, journeybuilder, einstein, einstein-recommendations

If STO setting is configured as "Send at Einstein's optimal default time".

For example, if STO is set for 4 hours and optimal time for subscribers with not enough data falls outside the 4 hours window.

Like if journey goes live at 9am with STO 4 hours then email activity but optimal time is 5pm, that means STO will still trigger the email within 4 hours window right? possibly end of 4 hours? and it is NOT going to hold the subscribers OUTSIDE the 4 hours window? assuming STO will pick optimal time within those 4 hours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each configured window has an optimal time for that window and that's when the email will be sent

Subscribers will also have an optimal time for each window.

For example, if you have a 4 hr window and the contacts reaches the step at noon, their optimal time for that window may be 2:00 pm. but if you have an 12 hr window configured and the contact reaches the STO wait at noon the optimal time maybe 5:00pm.

Additionaly each 24 hr window could have a different time, So on Monday it maybe 9:00am but on Tuesday it could be 1:00pm

Comment: Thanks EazyE this is great